# Finding the IP Address of a Router in a Daisy Chain

Tags: networking, router, ip-address

I'm trying to forward a port to my home computer so I can SSH to it when I'm away from home. Because I cannot get a good connection to my modem/router, I have to connect a second router to it. My home computer is connected to that router.

I forwarded the port to my desktop from the second router, but also need to forward that same port to the second router from the modem/router. To do that, I need to know the IP address of that router on the modem/router's network. Unfortunately, the modem/router uses the 10.0.0.x block, whereas the second router uses the 192.168.1.x block. How can I find the IP address of the second router in the modem/router's network?

Comment: In short, Don't use a second router to add on to a home network.  Do it correctly, if you need wired ports add a SWITCH and if you need more wifi coverage you want an additional ACCESS POINT or REPEATER.  You don't want two differnt subnets which is what you got now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Tyson already said in a comment, *you don't need a router*. To get more Ethernet ports, you only need a **switch**; and to extend WiFi network range, you only need a WiFi **access point**.

It just happens that the "home wireless routers" have a router, a switch, and a WiFi AP integrated in one device for convenience. But they're definitely **not meant to be daisy-chained**.

---

So, since you've already purchased the router, try running it in **pure bridge mode**, avoiding the 'routing' features and merely using it as an additional switch+AP.

Sometimes it's actually labelled "bridge mode", but sometimes you'll have to manually turn off DHCP and connect the router through its *LAN* port instead of WAN port.

---

Well, it is *possible* to make daisy-chaining work. But since that way you essentially create two separate networks, it means 1) it's a good thing that they use different IP ranges, 2) you must use different WiFi network names, which means you lose automatic roaming between the two.

So you would need to turn off NAT on the 'inner' router; then add a static *route* on the 'outer' router – for the 'inner' IP range and with the inner router as the route's gateway.

<sub>(That is, as long as your router allows it. I still cannot fathom the existence of "home *routers*" that lock away the ability to manually *set routes*, but such garbage actually exists.)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the helpful response. I got a gateway and hooked it up to the network. Now, I am able to open ports to the public Internet.